# How to use a object factory with contextlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, objectfactory

I need to write code that deals with different hardware setups. A prori I don't know which hardware is connected to my system. So I use a object factory that reads some identifiers from the hardware and returns a specialized object. I would like to combine this approach with contextlib but did find out that the object still exists outside the with block. In my case this is a problem as I need to close the connection to my device.

A minimal working example for my problem:

```
import contextlib

class Dog:
    def speak(self):
        print('wuff')

class Cat:
    def speak(self):
        print('miau')


@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_animal(n):
    print('buy animal')
    if n==0:
        yield Dog()
    else:
        yield Cat()
    print('lost animal')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with get_animal(0) as animal:
        animal.speak()
    animal.speak()
```

This yields

```
> buy animal
> wuff
> lost animal
> wuff
```

How can I modify this code such that the final `animal.speak()` results in a error? I know that I can use `del animal` to release animal but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: The variable won't be removed, but you should "close" your object when it exits the context. E.g. if you try that with an `open(...)` file object, trying `f.read()` after the `with` block results in a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`. What that means exactly for your devices, you decide. `ValueError: play operation on dead dog.`…?

Comment: You can use `weakref`, first store the main reference to the object in the `get_animal` scope and yield only `wekref` to this object. So after context exit, the main ref will be cleared, and the wekref will point to nothing.